# How to assign values to slots while creating a class in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new class that will automatically generate the values of its slots if those values are not given explicitly.

Here is my setClass code:

```r
TestClass <- setClass(
  "TestClass",
  slots = c( names = "character",
    values = "numeric"

            ),
  validity = function(object) {

    if (length(object@values) != length(object@names) ) {
      warning("The amount of parameter values is not equal to the amount of parameter names. All parameter values have been set to 1.")

      object@values <- rep(1, length(object@names))
    } else {
      object@values <- as.numeric(object@values)
    }
  } 
)
```

The goal is to have the TestClass class always generate a vector of 1s for the "values" slot, if the values are not provided.

When I run the code:

```r
test <- TestClass(names = c("a", "b"))
```

**I get the following error:**

```r
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “TestClass” object: 1: 1
invalid class “TestClass” object: 2: 1
In addition: Warning message:
In validityMethod(object) :
  The amount of parameter values is not equal to the amount of parameter names. All parameter values have been set to 1.
```

EDIT: I know I can use "prototype" in setClass to create my defaults. But as you can see I am trying to be self referential and check if the values provided for the class arguments meet certain conditions, and if they don't, override the input by assigning values to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled upon an answer from [Hadley Wickham](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html#s4-dispatch), but I'm not sure if it's less of a solution and more of a clever workaround.

I can apparently create a new class using the `new()` function. And then, using  `if` statements within `new()`, I have more control over the values of the slots.

```r
TestClass <- function(names, values = NA) {

  if (length(values) != length(names) ) {
    warning("The amount of parameter values is not equal to the amount of parameter names. All parameter values have been set to 1.")
    values <- rep(1, length(names))
  } else {
  values <- as.numeric(values)
  }

  new("TestClass", names = names, values = values)

}

TestClass_1 <- TestClass(names = c("a", "b") )
```