# What is the difference between new() and setClass() in R?

Tags: r, class, types, r-s4

I am curious as to what the functional difference is between between `new()` and `setClass()` in R?

I answered another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070863/how-to-assign-values-to-slots-while-creating-a-class-in-r) that seems to suggest that they operate identically, except that `new()` is potentially far less "restrictive."

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this link in the description on top of the page and the `Value` section:
[r documentation setClass](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.1/topics/setClass)

*From the link:*

> - A generator function suitable for creating objects from the class is
>     returned, invisibly. A call to this function generates a call to new
>     for the class. The call takes any number of arguments, which will be
>     passed on to the initialize method. If no initialize method is defined
>     for the class or one of its superclasses, the default method expects
>     named arguments with the name of one of the slots and unnamed
>     arguments that are objects from one of the contained classes.
> - Typically the generator function is assigned the name of the class,
>     for programming clarity. This is not a requirement and objects from
>     the class can also be generated directly from new. The advantages of
>     the generator function are a slightly simpler and clearer call, and
>     that the call will contain the package name of the class (eliminating
>     any ambiguity if two classes from different packages have the same
>     name).
> - If the class is virtual, an attempt to generate an object from either
>     the generator or new() will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions have completely different side effects. You *need* to call `setClass` when you are defining a class. You can't just do

```
new("square",x=0,y=0,side=1) -> mySquare
```

and expect R to know what a square is (you will get an error along the lines of "undefined class 'square'"). If you do

```
setClass("square",
  slots=c(
    x="numeric",
    y="numeric",
    side="numeric"
  )
) -> square

mySquare <- square(x=0,y=0,side=1)
```

then you have defined the class `square` and can then call the function `square` to create objects from it. You can also at this point call `new("square",...)` as well but the effect is the same.

If you want to create a constructor function that doesn't just take slot names as arguments, then the recommended approach is to create an ordinary function along the lines of

```
createSquare <- function(r,theta,side){
  square(x=r*cos(theta),y=r*sin(theta),side=side)
}
```